# Dropdown gets cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have one asp.net application, in which i have one dropdown which is binded to dataset. But after selecting one item, the drop down gets cleared all the value, How we can resolve this issue?

This is my dropdown list in design page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Width="300px"
            AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged">

        </asp:DropDownList>
```

and binding code is shown below.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BindProductDdl();
    }

    private void BindProductDdl()
    {
        Products objProducts = new Products();
        dsProducts dsProduct = new dsProducts();
        ListItem olst = default(ListItem);
        olst = new ListItem(" Select", "0");
        dsProduct = objProducts.GetDataset("");            
        ddlProduct.DataSource = dsProduct;
        ddlProduct.DataTextField = "Product";
        ddlProduct.DataValueField = "Id";
        ddlProduct.DataBind();
        ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, olst);
    }

 protected void ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Products objProducts = new Products();
        dsProducts dsProduct = new dsProducts();
        string criteria = "";

        if (ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Text != " Select")
        {
            string id = ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Value;
            criteria = "Id='" + id + "'";
            dsProduct = objProducts.GetDataset(criteria);
            productValue = Convert.ToDecimal(dsProduct.tblProducts.Rows[0]["Value"].ToString());
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post also sourcecode of the ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: Since the problem is occurring when you select an item, we'll need the SelectedIndexChanged code that Tim is requesting.

Comment: Do you have viewstate disabled for the page?

Comment: +1 for the ViewState option, quick test confirmed this cause exactly such behavior

Comment: I think you may clear the values in ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdown gets cleared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237910/dropdown-gets-cleared)

Comment: You've already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186663/dropdown-gets-cleared/4190599#4190599. You should comment there if the answers you are getting do not work.

Comment: i voted that thread for closing

Comment: @Dilse what's the point of helping you if you ignore the answers? question has been flagged.

Comment: Merged; please don't double-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question if I understand correctly you dont want the dropdown list to rebind if it is populated. Also please check your viewstate, this should not be happening, unless you have disabled viewstate

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
  if (!IsPostBack && ddlProduct.Items.count <=0 )
        BindProductDdl();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Set the AppendDataBoundItems property of the dropdown to true and this will allow you to have a mix of databound items and non databound items (otherwise that insert statement is clearing your list)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx

Comment: He's inserting the new item AFTER databinding occurs, so I don't think this is the problem. AppendDataBoundItems is meant for items that you add BEFORE databinding (like in your markup), hence the "Append" part.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have viewstate disabled on the page? Since you are only loading the items into the dropdownlist on the first load of the page, if viewstate is not enabled there will be nothing in the list after the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, but I've seen in other languages and false interpretation...

You have your product Value as convert of ToDecimal which implies 99.999 for example.

If your ID that you are binding to is based on a whole number (ie: Integer basis), the bound value won't match... even if Value = 1  vs Value = 1.00 it won't match and will not be considered a valid "value" that matches your list.  Convert your answer to a whole/integer number and it might do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full source for the page I am simply speculating, but have you disabled ViewState on the page? If so, the DropDownList cannot retain its values between postbacks and the lists will have to be reloaded each time.