# Dropdown gets cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropdown gets cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186663/dropdown-gets-cleared)

Hi

I have one asp.net application, in which i have one dropdown which is binded to dataset. But after selecting one item, the drop down gets cleared all the value, How we can resolve this issue?

This is my dropdown list in design page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Width="300px"
            AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged">

        </asp:DropDownList>
```

and binding code is shown below.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BindProductDdl();
    }

    private void BindProductDdl()
    {
        Products objProducts = new Products();
        dsProducts dsProduct = new dsProducts();
        ListItem olst = default(ListItem);
        olst = new ListItem(" Select", "0");
        dsProduct = objProducts.GetDataset("");            
        ddlProduct.DataSource = dsProduct;
        ddlProduct.DataTextField = "Product";
        ddlProduct.DataValueField = "Id";
        ddlProduct.DataBind();
        ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, olst);
    }

 protected void ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Products objProducts = new Products();
        dsProducts dsProduct = new dsProducts();
        string criteria = "";

        if (ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Text != " Select")
        {
            string id = ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Value;
            criteria = "Id='" + id + "'";
            dsProduct = objProducts.GetDataset(criteria);
            productValue = Convert.ToDecimal(dsProduct.tblProducts.Rows[0]["Value"].ToString());
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance..